# Android: Kotlin Collections.random() is repeating random character sequences between app sessions

Tags: android, kotlin, random

I am looking to generate a random alphanumeric value to append to a String for an Android app. We are appending 10 digits of randomness using Kotlins kotlin.collections.random

We are seeing intermittent collisions on this randomness within fairly small data sets (<10), and they only seem to occur between app sessions (e.g you can keep generating them without issue with no app restart).

Our extension method for appending randomness:

```
private val values = ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')

internal fun String.appendRandomCharacters(charactersToAdd: Int): String {
    val randomness = (1..charactersToAdd).map { values.random() }.joinToString("")
    return this + randomness
}
```

Running this in tests I can generate a million random strings without issue or collision.

However I can see that identical random strings are generated with high frequency if the app is killed and rerun.

I have done a fair bit of googling without much success so am hoping StackOverflow might be able to shed some light.

Comment: Have you tried to send a Random object inside random(), method, something like: values.random(Random(Clock.System.now().toEpochMilliseconds()))

Comment: How are you seeding your random number generator?  The difference between calling that function  1 million times in a row and restarting the app and calling it one time each is the second reseed the generator 1 million times.

Comment: That appears to be exactly the issue.  The random must be getting seeded the same way on app restart and leading to repeat values. 

If either of you would like to make it an answer I will mark it as accepted.  Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but magically it worked with java.util.Random class and with Kotlin i kept getting the same repeated 'random' values.